# How to display the image with aspected ratio?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-relativelayout

In my application I want to display the image with aspected ratio like the gallery.In my application I have to display the marker image on image.Because the marker image having dragging functionality.So that the following is the xml for that

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlayout"    
    android:id="@+id/imagelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in my activity after select the image from gallery, In onactivityresult method the following code  I am using.

```
                    try {
//                      bmGallayImage = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                        bmGallayImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                        bmRotated = InventorySubmitImagesActivity.rotateBitmap(bmGallayImage, orientation); 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    if(bmRotated!=null){
                        Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmRotated);

                        old_width=bmRotated.getWidth();
                        old_height=bmRotated.getHeight();
                        Log.e("gal bitmap height and width",""+old_height+"  "+old_width);
                        relImage.getLayoutParams().height = old_height;
                        relImage.getLayoutParams().width = old_width;
                        relImage.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

                    }
                    relImage.removeAllViews();
                    imgMarker = new ImageView(this);
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                    relImage.addView(imgMarker, layoutParams);
                    imgMarker.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                    bmdragImage=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_marker);
                    imgMarker.setImageBitmap(bmdragImage);
```

In this code relImage is the referance of relative layout and imgMarker is the referance of image view. And the gallery image is set to the relative layout.And My device resolution is 480 by 800 and image resolution is 1920 by 1080.So this is the out put i am getting.

[image] 
And gallery image view is like the bellow screen shot.

[image]

But my requirement is like the gallery image, i want to display the image with aspected ratio.So please suggest me how to do this. Thanks In Advance to all..

Comment: Is there any reason at all you are not using an `ImageView`? A background is not meant to be used to display images.

Comment: imgMarker.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitXY);

Comment: In that image I need another marker image,So that I have taken relative layout and add the marker image to that layout programatically. See the red marker image.

Comment: img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);   or specify some size to both width and height for the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with FrameLayout put image view in this and put your marker ImageView like [this](http://chiuki.github.io/images/android-layout-101/frame-layout-center.png)  http://chiuki.github.io/images/android-layout-101/frame-layout-center.png

Comment: Is is possible, if i change relative layout to image view

Comment: No you can do this easily with Frame layout.  can i ask why you ened to use relative layour?